# Established Linux processes

Tags: linux, mdm

We are running a IBM MDM server (initiate) which connects through a pooling mechanism to an Oracle DB server. The configuration of pooling has been set to 32. We also have a custom java process that submits data to this MDM server through an API that MDM server exposes. Once our custom java process (which does not open any DB connections directly) terminates, we see that the number of processes between MDM server and Db server has risen to some number greater than 32. After each nightly run, we see that the number of processes keeps on increasing and finally it reached the limit set by the Oracle DB (700) and the DB wont let any more connections to be opened to it and our process fails on that night. We are trying to figure why arent the processes getting terminated and why are they being still in ESTABLISHED mode (as per netstat command)

Comment: Can you please make it clear, what is the question?

Comment: `jstack`/`pstack` them to find what they are busy doing (or waiting for)

Answer (score 0):

There are several reasons the number of processes could increase and sockets in ESTABLISHED STATE.

Typical mistake is spawning a child process for each message/connect/register and not reusing the existing connection. Especially there are timer callbacks involved

e.g.,

```
c - register for timer callback -> server
c -> spawn a process to receive the reply and listen on receive socket
c - register for timer callback -> server -> server
c -> spawn a process to receive the reply and listen on receive socket
```

instead it should be

```
c - register for timer callback -> server
c -> spawn a process to receive the reply and listen on receive socket
c - set the initialized flag
c - register for timer callback -> server
c -> if initialized do not spawn a process to receive the reply
```

Comment: I am not exactly sure how the pseudo code you presented represents my situation. Can you explain ?

Comment: your custom java process is the client here. it is leaking processes.

Comment: How can I establish that for sure ? How does java leak processes as it itself runs in one process and terminates when jvm terminates ?

Answer (score 0):

Does the system suffers any exception after reaching the maximum limit?

Is the process created ares still active?

Are these process establishing the DB connection but not getting  terminated?

Did Top output shows the active process?

1)Clear the old logs.
2) lsof data. This is an operating system command, that will tell us
   what descriptors are being used by the app server process.
       lsof -p PID > lsof.out 
3) ulimits. These are the operating system resource limits
       ulimit -a > ulimits.out

Please check the code that opens the connection are getting closed once it is use?

Check the lsof output and the status of the connection type?

I am working for IBM as Java Service Engineer. Please answer the questions above so that we could help you better.

Comment: Here are the answers to your questions

Comment: Here are the answers to your questions 1) The exception  ERROR atesystems.hub.logging.NativeLog: ODBC [08001] [InitiateSystems][ODBC Oracle Wire Protocol driver][Oracle]TNS-12519: TNS:no appropriate service handler found 
2) lsof command gives a lot of line items for the SERVER process ID of the MDM engine. There are line item that has connections from MDM server IP:port number -> DB server (ESTABLISHED) which is the one that is causing the issue as there are 661 of those. 3) All of these 661 has the process ID of the MDM engine that is a server process 
3) The type of the connection is "IPV4"

Comment: One of the line item is shown below===> java    15313 mdmuser  322u  IPv4           88755633      0t0      TCP MDMserver:14532->DBServer:ncube-lm (ESTABLISHED)  ***** Where 15313 is the java process from the MDM Server

Comment: lsof output shows that it has connections with MDM server to DB server is that the expected behavior? Did you check the code that opens the connection are getting closed after use?

Comment: So the MDM server is opening to DB and retaining it for some reason. That is a packaged software by IBM and we did not do any customization for that.

Comment: Ok. Krish. This not  seems to be java related issue based on the above discussion But i could help you in identifying any descriptor leak . Add -Xdump:java+system:events:user jvm arguments and use kill -3 to collect javacore and system core. Javacore is text file which has threads running currently on the  java process. Investigate the threads that doing DB related operation to check the current state. System core is binary file  that stores  snap shot of process memory. Load the system core in https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/jdk/tools/memoryanalyzer/ to know about leaks